# What is the power of Lego Powered Up motors (M, L, and XL) and the Move Hub motors?

Tags: building, motor, moc, powered-up

I am trying to build a setup that includes two propellers that can pitch up and down. I am debating whether I should use two motor to power each propeller and the other two to act as servos for each of the "motor-propeller" set up, or the power of the motor is strong enough that I can use one motor/move hub to drive both propellers and the other motor can be used as a servo. Could you tell me the specs of these thing so I can decide which one to buy or order? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Philo is one of LEGO enthusiast and he did quite a number of tests with different motors produced by LEGO, which you can find  [here](https://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm). Table below is based on data measured by Philo:

| Motor | Torque | Rotation Speed | Mechanical Speed | Electrical Power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PUP M | 4.08 N*cm | 270 rpm | 1.15 W | 2.66 W |
| PUP Control+ L | 8.81 N*cm | 198 rpm | 1.83 W | 4.70 W |
| PUP Control+ XL | 8.81 N*cm | 198 rpm | 1.83 W | 4.16 W |
| PUP Move Hub | 4.08 N*cm | 264 rpm | 1.13 W | 3.37 W |